# Bumping multiple files with grunt bump

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

How would I have grunt bump, bump the version of multiple files in various folders? When I provide the grunt task more than two files, it only bumps the version for two of the three, and disregards the third.

Here is my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    bump: {
      options: {
        files: ["package.json", "./client/package.json", "./server/package.json"],
        commit: false,
        createTag: false,
        push: false,
        globalReplace: false,
        prereleaseName: false,
        regExp: false
      }
    }
  })
  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-bump")
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['bump'])
}
```

Comment: Is the third path that is being disregarded (i.e. `./server/package.json`) a valid path - does it actually exist ? It bumps all three files successfully here.

Comment: Hmm? That file exists. And if I switch the two paths say to have ./server/ before ./client/ it will instead bump the first two and disregard the package.json in the client directory.

Comment: FWIW - the version of `grunt-bump` I used was the latest, i.e. `grunt-bump@0.8.0'`  and tested also on both macOS and Windows.